# TypeError while using QTextEdit methods

Tags: python, string, user-interface, qstring, qtextedit

I have built a text editor using PyQt and I'm trying to display a string to it
I tried to use `QTextEdit.append()`, `QTextEdit.setText()` but I'm getting TypeError in each case.

I'm doing:

```
qstring_result = QString(string_result)
QTextEdit.setText(qstring_result)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: QTextEdit.append(QString): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QTextEdit'
```

I searched a lot but didn't get a way to convert `String type to QTextEdit type`. What is the way to tackle this?

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(100,100,1030,800)
        string_result = "This is correct output"
        qstring_result = QString(string_result)
        QTextEdit.setText(qstring_result)
        self.setWindowTitle("Writer")


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Main()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @matsjoyce Im new to python can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Could you show us more code? Somewhere you should have something like `something = QTextEdit()`. You need to do `something.setTest(qstring_result)`.

Comment: @matsjoyce I have edited the question.. it contains my code now.

Comment: Was that code generated by a tool, or did you write it from scratch?

Comment: @matsjoyce I'm learning python GUI. learning it from friend's notebook. He has written everything from some site..

Comment: By the style of the code, I'd guess he got it from zetcode, so looking at the tutorials there should help: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/

Comment: @matsjoyce I did the same way.. created my_obj = QTextEdit() and my_obj.setText(qstring_result). Now I'm not getting the error but still it hasn't set any text to text editor. Text editor is still a blank window.

Comment: @tryPy: matsjoice's suggestion is the answer to this problem. If you have a _new_ problem, you should create a new question (with the code that's actually relevant to the new problem).

Comment: But I can take a wild guess here: the `my_obj` is some random `QTextEdit` that you just created, not the `QTextEdit` bound to the actual edit box in the GUI, so calling `setText` on it has no visible effect.

Comment: @abarnert Do you think its worth putting that as an answer, or should this join the ranks of the unanswered?

Comment: @matsjoyce: If you can explain it well enough that it seems like someone at the asker's level should get it, I'd upvote it. Can't speak for anyone else, of course…

Comment: @abarnert I'll try my best, but if its downvoted, I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the method (function) of a class has to be called with an instance of the class:

```
>>> QTextEdit # class
<class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit'>
>>> QTextEdit() # instance
<PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit object at 0x7f00ea379a68>
>>> type(QTextEdit)
<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'>
>>> type(QTextEdit())
<class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit'>
```

The error messages show that the method is 'unbound', which means it has no instance attached:

```
>>> QTextEdit.setText # unbound
<built-in function setText>
>>> QTextEdit().setText # bound
<built-in method setText of QTextEdit object at 0x7f00ea379a68>
```

Therefore you must call your `setText` method on an instance of `QTextEdit`. You can create an instance of `QTextEdit` by calling it. You have to call the `QTextEdit`'s constructor with `self`, to show the `QTextEdit` what is master is (the window it is in). So far your program should be:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        string_result = "This is correct output"
        text_edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
```

You should then call the `setText` method. You should do `text_edit.setText`, not `QTextEdit.setText`, as `text_edit` is your instance. Therefore, your next line should be:

```
        text_edit.setText(string_result)
```

You can then finish your program:

```
        text_edit.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500) # this just sets the size to 500 x 500
        self.setWindowTitle("Writer")


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Your program then produces this output:

[image: window]

Also, as your program is in the general form of a zetcode tutorial, it might be worth checking them out: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/